# What's the "right" order to play the Grisaia Spin-offs?

Tags: grisaia

I just played through the main branch of the "Laybrinth of Grisaia" game, and afterwards went looking for the following game ("Eden of Grisaia" or something like that) in the steam store.

It seems it isn't released yet but I found three spin-offs:

- The Leisure of Grisaia
- The Melody of Grisaia
- The Afterglow of Grisaia

My question is, is there any order that I should take in playing these? I guess "Leisure" should be first, since the other two are spin-offs to the labyrinth and this to the original, but especially for "Melody" and "Afterglow" I'm not sure which to read first...

I'm sorry if this is off-topic for this side, but arqade didn't seem like the right place, either...

EDIT:
I found [this graph](https://vndb.org/v5154/rg) showing the relation between the different games but it didn't help me in deciding which of "Melody" and "Afterglow" to play first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leisure of Grisaia = Grisaia no yuukan
Melody of Grisaia = Grisaia no senritsu
Afterglow of Grisaia = Grisaia no Zankou
Le fruit de la grisaia = Grisaia no kajitsu
Le laberynth de la grisaia = Grisaia no Meikyuu
Le eden de la grisaia = Grisaia no Rakuen

Right order

1. Parent game: Grisaia no Kajitsu.
   Side story: Grisaia no yuukan
2. Sequel: Grisaia no Meikyuu.
   Side stories: Grisaia no senritsu and Grisaia no Zankou. Since you completed the main game the side stories can be played in any order.
3. Sequel: Grisaia no Rakuen

To summarize, by English names:

1. The Fruit of Grisaia (main)
2. The Leisure of Grisaia (side)
3. The Labyrinth of Grisaia (main)
4. The Afterglow of Grisaia (side)
5. The Melody of Grisaia (side)
6. The Eden of Grisaia (main)

(4 and 5 can be played in any order)

Comment: Source: knowledge I have. I also went to vndb and checked each VN to make sure I'm not mistaken.

Comment: ok, that's how far I got, too, by looking to vndb...
but goes zankou before senritsu or the other way round?

Comment: It doesn't matter. They literally take 1 hour to finish reading and aren't plot-driven. It's just a series of short stories to make you enjoy the characters you grew attached to. They also deal with some events previous to even the parent game.

Comment: Senritsu as some plot but it isn't very relevant.